# How does @SessionScoped work with EJB? Is CDI only for web-tier?

Tags: session, servlets, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

How is the **session** defined in `@SessionScoped` CDI bean?
Is this annotation valid only when called from Servlet container, where the session is well defined in form of `HttpSession`?

If not, than how an EJB with `@Inject @SessionScoped MyBean myBean` can know **what the session really is**? I mean, methods of this EJB could have been invoked by a standalone client, RESTful WS or by some other view.
What should happen in such case? Should the annotation have no meaning, should it inject fresh `MyBean` instance for each request or maybe it should retain the same instance across all requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [@SessionScoped specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP3/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html)

> The session scope is active:
>
> during the service() method of any servlet in the web application,
>   during the doFilter() method of any servlet filter and when the
>   container calls any HttpSessionListener, AsyncListener or
>   ServletRequestListener.

So in short, yes. It is bound to the HttpSession. Also:

> The session context is shared between all servlet requests that occur
>   in the same HTTP session. The session context is destroyed when the
>   HTTPSession times out, after all HttpSessionListeners have been
>   called, and at the very end of any request in which invalidate() was
>   called, after all filters and ServletRequestListeners have been
>   called.

Comment: Really, how else is a Session defined even for something like a SFSB? Of course there's nothing prohibiting you from creating your own scope and tying it to whatever you like.

Comment: @LightGuard, I guess that in SFSB the "session" lasts from SFSB instantiation to it's removal (or timeout). So as long as I have a reference to it, I'll hit the same environment (session).

Comment: @Gonzalo, thanks for this information. I wonder - what should happen if I'd use `@SessionScoped` bean in an environment where there is no such scope (i.e. REST WS as mentioned in question). Each request is treated as a new session? What about SFSB, as LightGuard mentioned. Will the `@SessionScoped` refer to the `HttpSession` session or the SFSB session?

Comment: My understanding is that @SessionScoped acts as the glue between the web layer and your EJBs. I doubt that the annotation would have any effect on a remote EJB called from a Swing client. Remember also that JSF session is backed by HttpSession too so it gets transferred to your EJBs as HttpSession.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check how the annotation will react upon REST invocation.

Comment: Just to update - in Glassfish 3.1.1 when `@SessionScoped` is used with REST - it treats every request as separate session, so every request has fresh instance created. Very reasonable.